# Characterization of a Subgroup via a Homomorphic Inclusion

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have encountered the following definition of a subgroup $H$ of a group $G$: A subset $H$ of a group $G$ is a subgroup of $G$ provided the inclusion $i_H :H \longrightarrow G$ is a homomorphism. I am trying to show that this characterization is equivalent to the "usual" definition that declares a subset of a group is a subgroup if it is itself a group.

So, suppose the inclusion is a homomorphism. The first thing I want to show is that
$H$ is stable under the group operation. This seems pretty straightforward: If $x,y \in H$ we have
$$
i_H(x)i_H(y) = i_H(xy) = xy \in \text{Im}(i_H) \implies xy \in H
$$

The first equality follows from the hypothesis that $i_H$ is a homomorphism and the second follows from the definition of the inclusion map and, finally, the last conclusion follows from the fact that $\text{Im}(i_H) = H$. So far so good, I believe.

I'm stuck though when trying to show that $H$ contains the identity element. Now, any homomorphism $\varphi$ from a group $E$ to another group $F$ will carry the group identity $e_E \in E$ to the group identity $e_F \in F$, i.e., $\phi(e_E) = e_F$. Would I be correct in saying that since $i_H$ is a homomorphism then $e_G$ must me in the image of $i_H$ and therefore must be in $H$?

This doesn't seem quite right to me because this more-or-less assumes that $e_G$ is in the domain of $i_H$ to begin with. But, this raises a second question in that what, precisely, does it mean for *any function* to be a homomorphism between a subset and a group?

Comment: Your 2nd paragraph's second sentence says «The first thing I want to show is that...» yet that is not quite right. If you suppose that the inclusion is an homomorphism, you are in particular supposing that $H$ is somehow a group. *What* group structure do you have in mind?

Comment: Well, I guess this goes to the difficulty, or at least my difficulty in understanding this; As I indicate in my last paragraph, doesn't calling $i_H$ a homomorphism presume, in fact, that $H$ is a group itself and not merely a subset?

Comment: That is precisely what I said :)

Comment: Where did you find this definition? That might help us sort things out.

Comment: What you can say is that the image of $i_H$ contains an element which is idempotent: that is, an element $x\in i_H(H)$ such that $x^2=x$. [Here $x=i_H(e_H)$.]  This element is thus also idempotent in $G$, so...

Comment: In fact, the comment of @SteveD furnishes one way of proving that a group homomorphism $H\to G$ (between arbitrary groups) maps the identity element of $H$ to the identity element of $G$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that the following formulation of the result of your question is mathematically correct and can be proven:

**Theorem** Let $G$ be a group and let $H$ be a *subset* of $G$. Let us assume that $H$ is a *group* (although we do not necessarily assume that the group structure of $H$ is inherited from $G$). If the inclusion map $i:H\to G$ is a group homomorphism, then $H$ is a *subgroup* of $G$, i.e., the group structure of $H$ *is* inherited from $G$.

*Proof*. Let us denote the group operation of $H$ by $\cdot$ and the group operation of $G$ by $\ast$. If the inclusion map $i:H\to G$ is a group homomorphism, then $i(x)\ast i(y) = i(x\cdot y)$ for all $x,y\in H$. In other words, the restriction of the function $\ast:G\times G\to G$ to $H\times H$ is the function $\cdot:H\times H\to H$. Therefore, $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. **Q.E.D.**

The converse of the theorem above is also true. I leave the formulation of the converse and its proof as a simple exercise. (*Hint*: In a sense, you simply need to "reverse all the implications" in the argument above.)

In some sense, the main difficulty present here is the *correct formulation* of the result you are trying to prove; once you have written down a correct formulation of what you wish to prove, then the proof is nothing more than a triviality.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, that was my problem; I had written in my notes the characterization in terms of a <i>subset</i> rather than a <i>subgroup</i> and didn't consider that was where the problem was! Thanks for clearing that up.